# Is assembly running in SQL Server or from a Windows app

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, clr

How can I determine if an assembly is running from a `SQL` Server `CLR` stored procedure or if it is running from a Windows app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [SqlContext.IsAvailable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.server.sqlcontext.isavailable.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Following code should return different assembly information in both cases.

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
```